# Wrong output for console .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Why the output is not what I want to...

Here's the code:

```
int num;
Console.WriteLine("Please input age: ");
num = Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

For example I input 5, the output is 53. It needs to be 5, what is happening on the code. Can somebody explain? Thank you.

Comment: Is there some relation between this example and a fact that you study ASP.NET ? If yes, please explain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns the character code of the next character in the stream. The ASCII character code of '5' is 53.

You need to read the whole line as a string

```
string str = Console.Readline();
```

and then `Parse()` it or `TryParse()` it.

```
 int num;
 try
 {  
     num = int.Parse(str);
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
     Console.Writeline("Not a number!");
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the documentation of the [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) method:

> Reads the next character from the standard input stream.

So this will returns the ASCII value of a single character that the user entered.

You need to read the entire line and parse the string back to an integer:

```
int num;
Console.WriteLine("Please input age: ");
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine(num);
```

of course this parsing might fail if the user enters an invalid integer. So you could handle it like this:

```
int num;
Console.WriteLine("Please input age: ");
if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid age");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(num);
}
```